# C# when video ends, close the active form

Tags: c#, media-player, wmp

I'm trying to close a form in which a video is playing. I want it to close said form when the video ends.

I'm using wmp embedded into my form, with ui mode hidden.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [PlayStateChange event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd562460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the player.

```
wmp.PlayStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(wmp_PlayStateChange);

private void wmp_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if(e.newState == 8)
       this.Close();
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If that's answered your question, you can click the check mark on the left to accept it as an answer :)